# VIM-style keyboard navigation in TextMate

Tags: vim, textmate

I'm using TextMate in OSX and would love it if I could enable VIM-style keyboard navigation using 'h','j','k','l' with a modifier key (like Control, Option, or Command). I know TextMate (somewhat) supports the Emacs-style of navigation, so this must be possible.

I tried using custom key-bindings in OSX as described on the TextMate site both [here](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/) and [here](http://manual.macromates.com/en/key_bindings.html) to no avail.

Has anybody accomplished what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "this must be possible"? What would make you think that? TextMate is not a modal editor.

Comment: I don't think it's so much that Textmate supports Emacs style navigation as it is Mac OS X does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a plugin](http://starvingcyclist.com/vimate) that tries to provide vi keybindings to TextMate, it has INSERT and NORMAL modes and only a few of vi's NORMAL mode commands.

It's fun to play with for a couple of minutes but it doesn't take more time to hit its many limitations.

If you like Vim's keybindings, why don't you use Vim? I've switched a few months ago, it's simply amazing.

Comment: As of today, github.com/philc/textmatevim doesn't work with textmate 2

Answer (score 4):

Bundles -> Macros -> Start Recording.

Press left arrow.

Bundles -> Macros -> Stop Recording.

Bundles -> Macros -> Save Last Recording...

Give it a name like "left" and set the Key Equivalent to Cmd-Shift-H or whatever.

Repeat for J, K, and L.